# begin iterator of map not working c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator, constants

We have `map`:

```
std::map<double, COLORREF> colorset;
```

Here I provide part of function which returns `colorref` by `value`

```
COLORREF GetColour(double value) const
{
   ...
   for(std::map<double, COLORREF>::iterator ii=colorset.begin(); ii!=colorset.end(); ++ii)
   {
    std::cout << (*ii).first << ": " << (*ii).second << std::endl;
   }
   ...
   return defaultColor;
}
```

But, compiler gives an error telling about nonexistance of converting from `tree_const_iterator`to`tree_iterator` in `colorset.begin()`.

If I delete const term from function everything is OK, but I must declare function as const.

Why this error is appearing?
Or can someone provide alternate way to iterate though map?

Comment: If you're not restricted from using C++11, the above mess becomes much more readable: `for (auto const & i : colorset) { ... }`

Comment: that gives an compiler error in visual studio 2010

Comment: VS2010 does not support that feature (VS2012 does though).  However, it does support this feature: `for (auto i=colorset.begin(); i!=colorset.end(); ++i) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use const_iterator:

```
   for(std::map<double, COLORREF>::const_iterator ii=colorset.begin(); ii!=colorset.end(); ++ii)
```

PS

I would use ii->first etc

Comment: Thanks! That works. Could you tell me difference between const function and usual function? Const function returns constant value?

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov `const` qualified functions are called instead of non-`const` qualified functions whenever the object it is being called from is `const`. So `const MyClass myObject; myObject.method();` will call the `const`-qualified `method` if there is (you'd get an error if there isn't).

Comment: @Nurlan Kenzhebekov : a const function does not modify the object. There is more to say about this subject. Being strict about const is a good practice, but sometimes difficult. Btw I guess answer can be accepted?